# Share functions using React Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a component for the logic of the component and another for the view.

I noticed that the previous developer of the project used to share functions between the logic component and the view instead of using props.

This is how the router is defined from de "logic" component and renders all de views instead of passing props.

Also, this is an awful way to route, right?

```
const OnboardingRouter = {
  [ONBOARDING]: OnboardingView,
  [COMPANY_DETAILS]: CompanyDetailsView,
  [OWNERS]: OwnersShipOnboardingView,
  [ENTITIES]: EntitiesOnboardingView,
  [CONTROL_PERSON]: ControlPersonView,
  [PLAID_FINANCIAL]: PlaidFinancialView,
  [LINK_ACCOUNT]: LinkBankAccountOnboardingView,
  [VERIFY_APPLICATION]: VerifyApplicationView,
  [OFFER_TERMS]: OfferTermsOnboardingView,
};

const RenderView = React.useMemo(() => {
    setRefreshKyb(true);
    return OnboardingRouter[pathname];
  }, [pathname]);

if (!RenderView) return <Navigate to={ONBOARDING} />;

  return (
    <OnboardingStore.Provider
      value={{
        KYB,
        loading: KYBRequest.isLoading,
        openVerifyModal,
        accountConnected,
        agreePlaid,
        getPlaidToken,
        isLineOfCredit,
        isLoans,
        isBankruptcy,
        isTaxes,
        isLawsuit,
        handleIsLineOfCreditChange,
        handleIsLoansChange,
        handleIsBankruptcyChange,
        handleIsBankruptcyClick,
        handleIsTaxesChange,
        handleIsTaxesClick,
        handleIsLawsuitChange,
        handleOpenPlaid,
        handleSetAgreePlaid,
        setKYB,
        handleOpenVerifyModal,
        handleCancelVerifyModal,
        handleAcceptVerifyModal,
      }}
    >
      <RenderView />
    </OnboardingStore.Provider>
  );
```

Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is not bad practice, But it is gonna load all the views instead you can simply use lazy() method force to react app load any file when it is needed